# Removing files created by another user with rsync

Tags: permissions, rsync, raspberry-pi, sudo

### Problem

I have the following scenario:

- [motion](https://github.com/Motion-Project/motion) is creating directories and files with the user:group `motion:motion` and the permissions `755`
- as a cron task, I'd like to periodically copy these files to a remote computer **and then delete them**. The command I'm trying to use is

  `sudo rsync -avz --remove-source-files /home/pi/Pictures/SecurityCamera/ username@host:/Users/username/Pictures/SecurityCamera`
- The files are **successfully copied to the remote** machine, however without the `sudo`, **the local files aren't deleted**. With the `sudo`, I'm required to enter my password for the remote machine, even though I've set up **public key authentication**.

---

### Attempted Solutions

I've tried changing a few settings in the remote *sshd_config* to no avail

```
PermitRootLogin without-password 
StrictModes no
```

I've also tried adding the both the `pi` and `root` user to the motion group, but looking more closely at the permissions, groups don't have write access to the files I'm moving.

---

### TL;DR

How can I use `sudo rsync` to delete local files created by another user without entering a password for the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you doing this on Raspberry Pi.

1. Add this string `pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to the `/etc/sudoers`
2. Add user `pi` to the group `motion`: `usermod -a -G motion pi`
3. Change directory permission where `motion` saving files to 775
   (`chmod -R 775 /path/to/motion/dir`)
   You can use now `sudo rsync` without providing a password but keep in a save place credentials for user 'pi' since it almost a `root` now

P.S.
Another way is to allow user `motion` to be a normal user by assigning a password and shell to him `sudo usermod -s /bin/sh motion; sudo passwd motion`
This way you can login for rsyncing as a user motion

P.P.S
Following comment, what actually you need is:

`echo '*/5 *   * * *   root  /usr/bin/rsync -avz --remove-source-files /home/pi/Pictures/SecurityCamera/ username@host:/Users/username/Pictures/SecurityCamera' | sudo /usr/bin/tee /etc/cron.d/saveMotionPics.task`

Comment: I'm calling rsync as a cron task. Aren't cron tasks always run as root?

Comment: Not really, if you using system cron then you need to specify user - who is going to run some program, kinda like that `*/5 *   * * *   motion   /pat/to/the/program/to/run.sh` where `motion` is a user who will actually `run.sh` P.S. of cause you can use `root` instead of `motion` - this way you dont need any sudo

Comment: I added right cron job to my answer after P.P.S. Just correct how often you want rsyncing, i set there every 5 minutes